# How do I get type checking to work with React forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having trouble getting type checking to work while using forwardRef. My code is as follows:

***Component:***

```
export interface Props {
  label?: string;
  callback: () => void;
}

export const _Button = (props: Props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Button = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <_Button { ...props } forwarded={ref} />
});
```

***Component Usage:***

```
export const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Application</h1>
      <Button label="foo" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can see I am not passing the required callback prop but typescript doesn't see an issue. Below is what I have tried and I still cannot get type checking to work.

```
export interface Props {
  label?: string;
  callback: () => void;
}

export const _Button = (props: Props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, Props>((props: Props, ref) => {
  return <_Button { ...props } forwarded={ref} />
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Added Image for response to answers 1 and 2. This is the typescript error I am expected to have.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to do smth like that:

```js
import React, { FC, forwardRef, ForwardedRef, createRef } from 'react'

export interface Props {
    label?: string;
    callback: () => void;
    forwardedRef: ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>
}

export const _Button: FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {


    return (
        <div ref={props.forwardedRef}>
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export const Button = forwardRef<
    HTMLDivElement,
    Omit<Props, 'forwardedRef'>
>((props, ref) => <_Button {...props} forwardedRef={ref} />);


export const App = () => {
    const ref = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Application</h1>
            <Button ref={ref} label="foo" callback={() => null} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) you can find documentation regarding refs.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I am still not getting the typescript error when I fail to add the required prop callback. Using your code if I export _Button straight away and bypass the forwardRef, and remove : React.FC<Props>, the typescript check works. I included an image of what I am talking about at the end of my initial post. As you can see I exported the _Button instead and type checking works. I still cannot get it to work with either or the answers above.

Comment: You should provide `callback` and `forwarderRef` properties to `_Button`

Comment: @Aaron please share in ts playground an example with error

Comment: This is strange, the type checking works properly in the code sandbox, just as I would expect it to work, even my code worked properly. However on my local machine using VSCode and Intelij the type checking is not showing the error when I fail to add a required prop. Maybe this is an editor issue. In the code sandbox I used your code and made the label required and the typescript error is seen as expected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-surf-kodow?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: if you get a chance please look at the sandbox. I am baffled with why I cannot get typescript to show the error when I fail to add required props.

Comment: Sorry, I\m bit confused. What are you expect? I see an error in codesandbox `Property 'label' is missing in type '{ callback: null; }' but required in type 'Pick<Props, "label" | "callback">'` . Do you want to fix this error?

Comment: Yeah I see it too, it does work in any of my editors including intellij and VSCode. I don't know, its a bit frustrating. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are pass down the `ref` by props of `_Button`. You should declare `forwarded` prop for `_Button` component with type: `React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>`.

```
type Ref<T> = RefCallback<T> | RefObject<T> | null;
```

```
import React from 'react';

export interface Props {
  label?: string;
  callback: () => void;
  forwarded: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>;
}

export const _Button = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>((props, ref) => {
  return <_Button {...props} forwarded={ref} />;
});
```

package versions:

```json
"typescript": "^4.0.3",
"react": "^17.0.1",
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. I am still not getting the typescript error when I fail to add the required prop callback. Using your code if I export _Button straight away and bypass the forwardRef,  the typescript check works. I included an image of what I am talking about at the end of my initial post. As you can see I exported the _Button instead and type checking works. I still cannot get it to work with either or the answers here.